# Blank space between canvas and grid layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy, and I've created a very basic GUI for data plotting. It consists of a plot on a figure canvas and a number of buttons (currently 4) arranged in a grid layout.

The problem is that I am unable to avoid having an empty space in between the buttons and the plot as seen below.

[Link to image since my user is new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peNl9.png)

What I'd like is for the buttons to have their current size and the plot to take up the remaining space, but is seems that no matter what I try, the grid seems to always take of 50% of the total height.

Both main and kv file is included below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = '''
<Meta>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

<Body>:
    GridLayout:
        width: root.width
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: 'Button 1'
            font_size: 20
        Button:
            text: 'Button 2'
            font_size: 20
        Button:
            text: 'Button 3'
            font_size: 20
        Button:
            text: 'Button 4'
            font_size: 20
'''

Builder.load_string(KV)

class Graph(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Graph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.graph())

    def graph(self):
        global fig1, ax, wid
        fig1 = plt.figure()
        ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot([],[])
        wid = FigureCanvas(fig1)
        return wid

class Body(Widget):
    pass

class Meta(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Meta, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Graph())
        self.add_widget(Body())

class Builder(App):
    def build(self):
        return Meta()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Builder().run()
```

As I said, I'm new to Kivy (and object oriented programming in general) and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Try to use `size_hint_y` for your `Body` and `Graph` widgets. e.g. `size_hint_y: 1` and `size_hint_y: 9` respectively (or whatever you see fit).

Comment: So, I basically found out what I have been doing wrong... I've been trying to change the size_hint of the grid layout when in reality, I needed to change Body. That makes me feel kinda stupid, but thanks for helping me think straight.